# Trying to add words under wordpress user avatar, use add_filter get_avatar but fail to return data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add some data under wordpress user avatar, I am using add_filter get_avatar, it doesn't show up anything. What did I miss?

```html
<?php

add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 1 , 1 );

   function my_custom_avatar( $avatar ) {
       //if I use echo, it works
               $data='<p>Genius</p>';
         return $avatar.$data;

   }

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you just use the standard priority, i.e. `add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' );`?

Comment: It doesn't return any data. No error, but nothing happen either

Comment: It works for me. So your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I know what the problem is, add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_custom_avatar' , 10 , 1 ); the 1 need to change to 10,  Why?

Comment: Changing it to ten is the same as removing it. That is what I wrote in my first comment. It is the priority for the filter. Maybe you were filtering to early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering too early -  with a priority of 1. Either change this to 10 or greater (10 is the default) or remove it altogether.

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'my_custom_avatar' );
```

Or

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'my_custom_avatar', 20 );
```

You can leave out the last argument as well, as 1 is the default here (defines how many arguments are passed to your filter function).